# Apply HTTP to one area of HTTPS website running on Apache

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

I run a secure website on Apache, but one part requires YouTube videos that aren't showing due to the SSL blocking them.

I therefore need to use HTTP for this part of the site (/videos). If I delete the 's' off https, it jumps back in there so can't simply change the link to it.

Is there a mod_rewrite code or something similar that might add an exception to this directory?

Answer (score 1):

Switching from HTTPS to HTTP will always cause problems, especially if your users are authenticated and if you want to maintain security.

You could use YouTube via HTTPS instead, as described on the [YouTube API Blog](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/02/https-support-for-youtube-embeds.html).

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I've taken a look at this and think I can do what I want with this info at hand. Really appreciate your comments. Paul